# Entity Framework throwing Null entry error at Saving, C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am working on Entity Framework 6 and repositories setup to do crud operations. I am trying to insert record in one of the table and getting error for null entries even duo it is not.

```
{"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UI_ID', table 'Blackpool_BPM.dbo.COURSE_INSTANCE'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

[image]

The connection to database is correct as I can read data with no problem

### At Generic Repository, getting data correctly, just before Save()

[image]

### Table Structure

[image]

### Class Model

```
 [Table("COURSE_INSTANCE")]
public class BIZCourseInstanceEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int UI_ID { get; set; }

    public string UnitInstanceCode { get; set; }

    public string FESLongDescription { get; set; }

    public string FESShortDescription { get; set; }

    public string FullDescription { get; set; }

    public string OwningOrganisationCode { get; set; }

    public int? OwningOrganisationID { get; set; }

    public string TopicCode { get; set; }

    public string UnitCategory { get; set; }

    public string UnitCode { get; set; }

    public string FESQualificationType { get; set; }

    public int? SCHOOLS { get; set; }

    public int? MARKETING_GROUPS { get; set; }
}
```

### Repository

```
 public class BIZCourseInstanceRepository : GenericRepository<BIZCourseInstanceEntity>
{
    public BIZCourseInstanceRepository() { }

    public BIZCourseInstanceRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        :base(dbContext)
    { }
}
```

### Unit of work class

```
  public class BIZ_UOF : IDisposable
{
    private BIZDbContext _BIZDbContextObject = new BIZDbContext();

    protected BIZCourseInstanceRepository _BIZCourseInstanceRepository;

 public BIZCourseInstanceRepository BIZCourseInstanceRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._BIZCourseInstanceRepository == null)
            {
                this._BIZCourseInstanceRepository = new BIZCourseInstanceRepository(_BIZDbContextObject);
            }

            return _BIZCourseInstanceRepository;
        }
    }
    /////

   public void Save()
    {
        _BIZDbContextObject.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

        _BIZDbContextObject.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _BIZDbContextObject.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

### DbContext

```
public class BIZDbContext : BaseContext<BIZDbContext>
{
    public BIZDbContext() : base("_DbContext")
    { }

    public DbSet<BIZCourseInstanceEntity> BIZ_CourseInstance { get; set; }     
}
```

### Generic Repository CRUD

```
 public void InsertEntity(TEntity obj)
    {
        _DbSet.Add(obj);
    }
```

### Function class where Error is generating at Save()

```
  public void InsertCourseInstance()
    {
        BIZCourseInstanceEntity BIZCourseInstanceEntityObject = null;

        BIZCourseInstanceEntityObject = new BIZCourseInstanceEntity
        {
            UI_ID = 999999,
            UnitInstanceCode = "KZ999999",
            FESLongDescription = "LONG",
            FESShortDescription = "SHORT",
            FullDescription = "FULL",
            OwningOrganisationCode = "E",
            OwningOrganisationID = 155,
            TopicCode = "04.1",
            UnitCategory = "04",
            UnitCode = "HE-G", 
            FESQualificationType = null,
            SCHOOLS = 5,
            MARKETING_GROUPS = 44

        };

        using (var _uow = new BIZ_UOF())
        {
            _uow.BIZCourseInstanceRepository.InsertEntity(BIZCourseInstanceEntityObject);

            _uow.Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes it is null able

Comment: Just for fun, if you exclude UI_ID, just don't set it to 999999, remove that line.

Comment: Oh excuses, didn't read well.

Comment: Do you have any other mapping like Fluent Mapping in your `BIZDbContext`'s or `BaseContext`'s `OnModelCreating` method where you specify that `UI_ID` should be an `Identity` or `Computed` type? Setting that would exclude it from the generated `INSERT` sql statement and explain the Exception.

Comment: ^--- (continue) -- And I understand you want to force the insert but if the model is set to exclude it based on an erred setting above and the database is configured to not generate a value then the Exception would occur as soon as you try to insert into that table from your EF. The fix is then to correct the model mapping and remove the `Identity` or `Comptuted` flag.

Comment: no I am not using Fluent Mapping.. I try to change model definition to see if it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer, the problem was in my database I am require to provide the Primary key which in my case is UI_ID but in my model I haven't define DatabaseGeneredOption.None, hence throwing error, Thanks for Krillgar guiding me

here is updated model

```
[Table("COURSE_INSTANCE")]
public class BIZCourseInstanceEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UI_ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string UnitInstanceCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FESLongDescription { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FESShortDescription { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FullDescription { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string OwningOrganisationCode { get; set; }

    public int? OwningOrganisationID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string TopicCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string UnitCategory { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string UnitCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FESQualificationType { get; set; }

    public int? SCHOOLS { get; set; }

    public int? MARKETING_GROUPS { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Entity Framework that your ID is an identity field. If it isn't set up as that in the database, then you need to do that. Otherwise, you'll need to query for the next available ID, and then hope you don't collide with another request trying to save something at the same time.

```
[Table("COURSE_INSTANCE")]
public class BIZCourseInstanceEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UI_ID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

If you **absolutely** have to work without any sort of database generated options for your Primary Key, you can instead use the `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` value of the enum. This should be avoided to prevent collisions on your PK, but the option does exist.

Comment: no still got same error, also it is not auto generated key, I am sending value to it

Comment: Well if you're using the same ID and forcing it to `INSERT`, then I could see an exception being thrown. Perhaps they're not looking close enough to what error is being returned by SQL Server, as this is a rather edge case. You really should be letting the database set the ID.

Comment: Is UI_ID  autogenerated by database? I mean, does it have identity especification with autoincrement 1 for example?

Comment: You can't see it in what was provided, but as the PK on the table, it really should be. I made an (evidently) incorrect assumption, however I think that now becomes an X-Y problem. If OP's trying to set the PK manually in the C# code, then plenty of other errors are soon to emerge.

Comment: the problem is I am trying to inject data in BIZAGI table and I cannot change its schema structure otherwise application itself won't work

Comment: I change key definition with [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] and it worked ... many thanks, plus vote for that!

Comment: That works too. Evidently since it is the PK on the table, it has to be told SOMETHING. I've just never worked with a table whose keys weren't also identities.